# How to use Cloudtrail to get who created IAM user

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-cloudtrail

How to use Cloudtrail to get who created IAM user , how to get this from logs

Comment: I've noticed that all almost your questions got answered yet not a single answer was [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86979). Accepting useful answers is not only a good practice, but reduces duplicates and increases chances of your questions being actually answered.

Answer (score 9):

- If the IAM user was created inside the last 90 days, you can find who created the user using CloudTrail Event history.

  - Using the AWS CLI:
    `aws cloudtrail lookup-events --lookup-attributes AttributeKey=EventName,AttributeValue=CreateUser --region us-east-1`
  - Using the Console: Go to Event History in CloudTrail Service, choose the EventName filter with a value of CreateUser. You have to use the region us-east-1 to view the events.
- If the IAM user was created outside the 90 days time window, you can still find out who created the user if you have a trail enabled in CloudTrail. You can use Amazon Athena or some other method to search the log files created by CloudTrail in S3.

References:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/view-cloudtrail-events-cli.html (Note the disclaimer for global services post November 22, 2021)
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/view-cloudtrail-events-console.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cloudtrail-logs.html

Comment: Key thing to NOTE is use region as `us-east-1`. you will not see CreateUser event in your region.